# Using jquery-ui-map to bring in XML for points and Info Window

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

I am using jquery-ui-map (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to render golf courses on a map.  I am bringing in the courses through an XML feed.  I can get the points to render correctly, but each info window is exactly the same (the last item in the XML feed).

URL: http://www.madebysprung.com/playground/gmaps/test/

XML: http://www.madebysprung.com/playground/gmaps/test/map.xml

I am building the HTML for the info box in the variable called "markerhtml".  I then pass markerhtml to the content of the info box.

I appreciate any help you can give me on this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue.  You didn't declare a local variable named markerhtml in your code.  You can add it below the lat and long variables.

```
lat = $(this).find("lat").text();
long = $(this).find("long").text();
var markerhtml;
```

Also, note that you should rename the variable from "long" to "lng" (or something else).  long was a reserved word in JS at one point.  It's a bit cleaner to not use it.

Comment: Thanks Andres!  This worked great and I cleaned up that "long" variable.  Thanks again!